# R, generate pretty plot by dfSummary

Tags: r, summarytools

I have a problem using summarytools packet. There is tutorial:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/Introduction.html with pretty plots of data:
[image]
My problem is that my code generate only **TEXT GRAPH**. This is chunk of code in my markdown to generate plot:

````
```{r summary, results='markup'}
library(summarytools)
my_data <- ...
dfSummary(my_data)
```
````

Unfortunately it generates something like this:
[image]
How can I generate this pretty report using summarytools?
Or have you better tools for this? (generate graph, mean, std, etc.)

---

I found the correct syntax to generate plot:

```
print(dfSummary(baseline_train), method = 'render')
```

And the results look like this:
[image]

Comment: Use `dput` for data not images.

Comment: From the vignette you link to: *"It is also possible to use dfSummary() in Rmarkdown documents. In this next example, note that due to rmarkdown compatibility issues, histograms are not shown."*; the syntax should be `dfSummary(my_data, plain.ascii = FALSE, style = "grid")` to show an HTML table (without the histograms).

Comment: @MauritsEvers I try this syntax, the results is still the same

Comment: @NelsonGon regarding data we can try it on diamonds, a dataset from ggplot2.

Comment: @Cezary.Sz You need to use `results = 'asis'` instead of `results = 'markup'`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little update on this:

- **Always** use knitr chunk option `results='asis'`, as someone pointed in an earlier comment.
- It is possible to generate summaries including *png* graphs using `print()`:

  `print(dfSummary(iris), method = "render")`
- Starting with version 0.9.0 (available only on [GitHub](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools) as of Feb. 2019), *markdown summaries* will also include *png* graphs provided you specify the following arguments:

  - `plain.ascii = FALSE`
  - `style = "grid"`
  - a physical location for temporary *png*'s (`tmp.img.dir`)

    `dfSummary(iris, plain.ascii = FALSE, style = "grid", tmp.img.dir = "/tmp")`

**Additionnal tips**

- In both cases, you will (in all likelihood) need to adjust the size of the graphs with `dfSummary()`'s `graph.magnif` parameter (try values between `.75` and `.85`).
- Exclude a column or two to avoid overly wide summaries:
  `dfSummary(iris, [...], varnumbers = FALSE, valid.col = FALSE)`

Comment: Is it possible to get the results as an MS Excel table?

Comment: The table produced by the function is a data frame, so you can try exporting it to Excel with one of the numerous packages that can do that (xlsx is one of them). But the png graphs will be lost and the formatting will most probably need manual tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `results = 'asis'` for the code chunk. Here is minimal reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(summarytools)
dfSummary(iris, plain.ascii = FALSE, style = "grid")
```
````

produces

[image]

Comment: you generate TEXT GRAPH. I don't want to it. I need GRAPH.

Comment: @Cezary.Sz Please re-read my comment (and the vignette) again. It's very clearly stated in the latter that `dfSummary` does *not* produce histograms when used in an RMarkdown document. Also, above table is not plain text (as in your example) but a HTML table.